# error 'extern' and later 'static'

Tags: c++, static, extern

If i declare a function  in a file named ppmformat.h

```
//file ppmformat.h
namespace imaging
{
Image * ReadPPM(const char * filename);
} //namespace imaging
```

... and define it in ppmformat.cpp

```
static imaging::Image * imaging::ReadPPM(const char *filename)
{
 ....
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'imaging::Image* imaging::ReadPPM(const char*)' was declared 'extern' and later 'static' [-fpermissive]

```
    //ppmformat.h
    #ifndef _PPM
    #define _PPM

    #include "Image.h"
    namespace imaging
    {
    /*! Reads a PPM image file and returns a pointer to a newly allocated                  Image object containing the image.
    *
    *   \param filename is the null-terminated string of the name of the  file to open.
    *
    *  \return a pointer to a new Image object, if the read operation was successful, nullptr otherwise.
    */
    Image * ReadPPM(const char * filename);
    } //namespace imaging

    #endif

   //ppmformat.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include<string.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>
   #include "ppmformat.h"

   using namespace std;

   imaging::Image * imaging::ReadPPM(const char *filename)
   {
   ......
   }

   //Image.h

   #ifndef _IMAGE
   #define _IMAGE

   #include "Color.h"
   #include <iostream>

   namespace imaging
   {
    class Image
    {
    ....
    }
   }

  //Image.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Color.h"
  #include "Image.h"
  ....
  //end of Image.cpp

  //Color.h
  #ifndef _COLOR
  #define _COLOR
  namespace imaging
  { 
    Class Color
    {
    ....
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you define the function `static` in your source file?

Comment: Good question, upvoted.

Comment: if i delete static i take"multiple definition of `imaging::ReadPPM(char const*)"! Do you think there is a problem with the include files?

Comment: How do you build your project? Do you `#include` the *source* file anywhere? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Together with how you build?

Comment: The "multiple definitions" sounds like you're *including* the `.cpp` file. Don't do that. Compile it separately. Or else, place the definitions in the header and add `inline` to each function.

Comment: you are right. I have the cpp file in main. i was using previous code in main!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Code that declares the same entity with different linkages is invalid.

*C++11 §7.11/8 (dcl.std/8):*

> **”** The linkages implied by successive declarations for a given entity shall agree. That is, within a given scope,
>   each declaration declaring the same variable name or the same overloading of a function name shall imply
>   the same linkage. Each function in a given set of overloaded functions can have a different linkage, however.

For the in-practice, g++ 5.1.4 refuses to compile it, while unfortunately Visual C++ 2015 accepts it as a language extension, with a warning:

```
[C:\my\forums\so\257]
> g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'imaging::Image* imaging::ReadPPM(const char*)':
foo.cpp:9:62: error: 'imaging::Image* imaging::ReadPPM(const char*)' was declared 'extern' and later 'static' [-fpermissive]
 static imaging::Image * imaging::ReadPPM(const char *filename)
                                                              ^
foo.cpp:5:13: note: previous declaration of 'imaging::Image* imaging::ReadPPM(const char*)'
     Image * ReadPPM(const char * filename);
             ^
foo.cpp: At global scope:
foo.cpp:9:54: warning: unused parameter 'filename' [-Wunused-parameter]
 static imaging::Image * imaging::ReadPPM(const char *filename)
                                                      ^

[C:\my\forums\so\257]
> cl foo.cpp
foo.cpp
foo.cpp(10): warning C4211: nonstandard extension used: redefined extern to static
foo.cpp(9): warning C4100: 'filename': unreferenced formal parameter
foo.cpp(9): warning C4505: 'imaging::ReadPPM': unreferenced local function has been removed

[C:\my\forums\so\257]
> _
```

With a compiler that accepts this with a warning, it can be a good idea to turn that warning into a hard error. With Visual C++ that's option `/we4211`.

Comment: when i compiled in visual studio 2015 it was ok!
in cmd, compiled with gcc i take this error!

Comment: @madrugadas25845: You probably need to up the warning level in the Visual Studio project properties. I compiled with the following `CL` (environment variable) value: `CL=/nologo /EHsc /GR /W4 /FI "iso646.h"`.

Comment: /W4 can often be problematic.  Certainly in the past, many MS headers gave warnings at /W4 - in fact so many that warnings in ones own code were invisible.  In the past I tended to /W3, and then I could switch on /Werror.

Comment: @MartinBonner: It's no longer a problem. `/W4` is perfectly OK now. However, don't use `/Wall` with the Visual C++ compiler. ;-)

Comment: /W4 - That's EXCELLENT news.